# Weight Suspended From A Springlike Belt

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring, statics

This situation is similar to the physics involved in a slack line, though I'm looking at it for some CNC applications.

There is a 3meter belt, that is tightened to be under 200N of tension between two fixed points (attached with a swivel). Assume the weight of the belt itself is negligible.

Once tightened - a mass is then suspended in the middle which applies 400N of force downwards. This should dramatically increase the tension forces on the belt.

The belt functions like a very stiff spring; it has the property that it takes 25,000 N to cause a 1% increase in length.

Is there a closed form solution to the deflection and new tension force on the line?

[image: Problem Description]

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You start with a slack belt that is going to be tensioned between two fixed points $S$ distance apart. The free length $\ell_0$ is unknown at this point.

   [image: fig1]
2. You stretch $\ell_0$ into $S$ such that the tension force $T_1 = 200\,N$. Use the stiffness $k=833.3\,\text{kN/m}$ (from load to get 0.01% deflection @ 3 meters)

   [image: fig2]

   The tensioning force is specified, and is a result of stretching the free length  to the span $S$.

   $$ T_1 = k ( S - \ell_0 ) \tag{1}$$

   This is used to find the free length $$\ell_0 =S - \frac{T_1}{k}\tag{2}$$
3. Now when the weight $W$ is supported, the length of the belt is stretched to $\ell$ and a angled tension develops

   [image: fig3]

   The tension due to stretching is $$T = k ( \ell - \ell_0 ) \tag{3}$$ and the vertical component of the tension supports the weight to have a force balance of $$ 2 T \sin \theta = W \tag{4}$$

   From geometry we known that $\sin \theta = \frac{\delta}{\ell/2}$ where $\delta$ is the midpoint sag. Also we know that $\cos \theta = \frac{S}{\ell}$.

   All of the above can be summarized with the following 3 non-linear equations, to be solved for angle $\theta$, deflection $\delta$ and tension $T$

   $$\begin{aligned}
     2 T \sin \theta & = W \\
     T & = k S \left( \frac{1}{\cos \theta} - 1\right) \\
     \tan \theta & = \frac{\delta}{S/2}
    \end{aligned} \tag{4,5,6}$$

   The solution reduces down to solving (4) (5) for $\theta$ and using (6) get $\delta$. This means solving the following non-linear equation

   $$ W = 4 \delta \left( k - \frac{S k - T_1}{\sqrt{S^2+4 \delta^2}} \right) \tag{7} $$

   Using an approximation with limited number of higher order terms, that includes the effect of stiffness, a possible solution is

   $$ \delta \approx \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{W S^2}{k} \right)^{1/3} \left( 1 - \frac{T_1}{S k} \left( \frac{2}{3} \left( \frac{S k}{w} \right)^{2/3} - \frac{1}{3} \right) \right)  \tag{8}$$

So for example with $S=3\,\text{m}$, $T_1 = 200\,\text{N}$, $k=833,333\,\text{N/m}$ and $W=400\,\text{N}$. I calculate $\delta \approx 0.080\,\text{m}$

Comparing the above with the exact solution (numeric) I get a 0.1% difference in the payload  force to get the same deflection.

Comment: I think it's possible to write your Eq. (7) (missing its number?) as a fourth-order polynomial in $\cos \theta$, so it can in principle be solved in closed form.  But it probably wouldn't be a terribly illuminating expression.

Comment: @Lucid I updated the approximation and it is now much closer to the actual solution.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - reduced the problem into a 3rd order poly and solved it with Eq (8) (updated). The governing equation is $$ \frac{W/2}{S\; k} =  \tan \theta +  \left( \frac{T_1}{S \;k}-1 \right) \sin \theta$$ with $\tan(\theta) = \frac{\delta}{S/2}$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the updates!

Answer (score 0):

If each half of the belt acts like a spring, then:  2.5E4 N = k(.01)(1.5m) and k = 16.667E5 N/m.
For equilibrium at the junction: 2(T + ΔT)sin(θ) = 400 N  also   ΔT = k(ΔL) for each half, and 1.5 = (1.5 + ΔL)cos(θ), where θ is measured from the horizontal, ΔT is the increase in tension, and ΔL is the increase in length (for each half of the belt).  This gives 3 equations with 3 unknowns: ΔT, ΔL, and θ.
Considering the initial stretch, you might want to use 1.50012 m instead of 1.5 as the starting length of each half of the belt.  Since you have numeric values, these equations can be solved by the “Solver” on an Excel spreadsheet.  Or you can solve for sine and cosine, square and add to eliminate θ, reduce the 3 equations to one, and use “Goal seek” or Newton's method to solve for the remaining unknown.